# rvm: Syntax error when I'm trying to install on a machine running SME Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, rvm, rhel

I'm trying to set up a Rails server to run an app that I just wrote on a box running SME Server 7.4.

I've installed `curl`, `zlib`, and `readline`, but when I run the `rvm` script, I get this output:

```
$ bash < <(curl -sk https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
Cloning into rvm...
remote: Counting objects: 4757, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2427/2427), done.
remote: Total 4757 (delta 3082), reused 3183 (delta 1672)
Receiving objects: 100% (4757/4757), 1.57 MiB | 1.54 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3082/3082), done.
bash: line 298: syntax error near unexpected token `"--trace"'
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

Turns out that I was running an super-old version of `bash`. Installing 4.2 fixed this, and RVM installed perfectly.

For the record, RVM needs `bash` v3.2 or better.